# JavaScript Поиск по массиву, состоящему из JSON

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, find

Добрового времени суток..
Имеется такой массив

```
let arr = [
    {
        "TYPE" : "ТИП0",
        "NAME" : "ИМЯ0",
        "VALUE" : "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ0"
    },
    {
        "TYPE" : "ТИП0",
        "NAME" : "ИМЯ1",
        "VALUE" : "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ1"
    },
    {
        "TYPE" : "ТИП3",
        "NAME" : "ИМЯ3",
        "VALUE" : "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ3"
    }
```

Каким образом можно вытащить **VALUE** по выборке **(TYPE&&NAME)**?
т.е. по типу = тип0 и имени = имя1 выдать значение = значение1

Comment: *Это у вас не JSON, а ассоциативный массив (или просто 'объект'). А JSON - JavaScript Object Notation — тот же объект/массив, представленный в виде строки.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, не совсем тот же, у JSON намного более строгие правила

Answer (score 3):

Передаешь в сравнение по какому типу и имени сравнивать и оно отсеевает остальное

```js
let result = arr.filter((item) => item.TYPE === "ТИП3" && item.NAME === "ИМЯ3");
let value = result[0].VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска конкретного элемента по условию можно воспользоваться методом [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
let result = arr.find((item) => item.TYPE === "ТИП3" && item.NAME === "ИМЯ3");
```

В случае отсутствия подходящего элемента будет возвращен `null`.